# Why does this logger not create Sentry events?

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

I'm using django and sentry-sdk. In my django settings' logger section I have the following handler:

```
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'level': 'WARNING',                                     
        'handlers': ['console', ],                    
        'propagate': False
    }
}
```

And the sentry-sdk is initialized as follows:

```
import logging                                                                    
import sentry_sdk                                                                 
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration                      
from sentry_sdk.integrations.logging import LoggingIntegration

sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(                                              
    level=logging.INFO,
    event_level=logging.ERROR
)                                                                                 
sentry_sdk.init(                                                                  
    dsn="...",              
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), sentry_logging],                           
)
```

However, the following example does not send an error event to sentry

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
logger.error('Why do I not appear in sentry?')
```

On the other hand, others do, as for example

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('another_module')
logger.error('And why do I do appear in sentry?')
```

Question: How can I fix this for modules with `propagate=False`?

Comment: By setting propagate to true? or adding the sentry handler to your handlers (you only have 'console')

Comment: @dirkgroten neither answer would solve the problem. The new sentry sdk works different from Raven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sentry_sdk's django integration that actively sets the logger to be ignored

```
ignore_logger("django.server")
ignore_logger("django.request")
```

[https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/**init**.py#L90](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py#L90)

Comment: Ah, yeah. Don't use those loggers for anything important :) There are so much garbage errors on this logger, doing more sophisticated filtering would probably mean that I have to apply a regex against the log message.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer don't mind, but I would at least make it clear in the documentation or with parameter defaulted to ignored them. Would have saved me quite some headheach ;) Anyway, thanks for the fast feadback!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking there are three ways I can think of that a log message can not turn out as event:

- The `event_level` parameter is set too high (error by default, do `init(integrations=[LoggingIntegration(event_level=logging.DEBUG)])`
- Your logger's level is too high (do `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`)
- Your logger has a filter that filters out these messages (check `logger.filters` for emptyness)

In your case I can only think of the latter case applying.

Comment: Ok, it’s different than raven. Learning something every day :) but I don’t understand your answer. If the level is set to WARNING then it also logs ERROR level messages. How would setting it to ERROR make any difference?

Comment: You're right, that was a brainfart of me. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Updated and undeleted answer. I don't really know what OP's particular problem is but this should serve as good generic troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer it is actually a change you introduced into the django integration ;)

Comment: I have to admin that it was an XYproblem.. I should have specified the module from the beginning. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. I see how this can be confusing behavior but I hope you understand why I did this in the first place.